# OLEDB error with OLAP cube offline

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, ssas, olap, cube

I have a server machine with SQL Server 2008 R2 (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64))

On my machine I have Office Professional Plus2013.

I'm able to connect to any of my OLAP cube databases and browse the cubes through a pivot table with Excel 2013.  But, for some reason I'm not able to create an offline cube, when I try to do it I get the following error message:

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services: OLE DB Error: OLE DB or ODBC error: The following system error occurred: ; Either a connection cannot be made to the  server, or Analysis Services is not running on the computer specified..

The service is up and running; using excel pivot table I'm able to browse the cube.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check connectivity to Analysis Services as described in this [Technet discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb370e91-65a4-4b7c-b5be-de8a529a5c1b/excel-2013-create-offline-cube-error?forum=officeitpro).